# What is the equivalent CentOS for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6?

Tags: centos, rhel, virtualbox

I'm looking for a VirtualBox image which is most similar to RHEL 7.6.
Here [https://www.osboxes.org/centos/#centos-782003-vbox] I found CentOS 7.9 and 7.8 but the lower versions have different naming rule, so it is hard to find the right counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always download CentOS 7.6 and install it manually: https://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/isos/x86_64/

Answer (score 0):

According to CentOS' download site at the [Archived Versions](https://wiki.centos.org/Download#Archived_Versions) entries:

Release `7 (1810)` is Based on RHEL Source (Version) `7.6` and its archive Tree is at: https://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/

To install from ISO:

https://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/isos/x86_64/

And the Virtualbox image from OP's site (disclaimer: I don't know how trustworthy it can be) would be there:

https://www.osboxes.org/centos/#centos-7-1810-vbox